# What causes there to be an offset between the light lensing through the space neighboring galaxy clusters and the galaxy clusters themselves?

Tags: spacetime, dark-matter, mass-energy, gravitational-lensing, galaxy-clusters

http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2013/01/musket-ball-dark-force/

> The reason this is strange is that dark matter is thought to barely interact with itself. The dark matter should just coast through itself and move at the same speed as the hardly interacting galaxies. Instead, it looks like the dark matter is crashing into something — perhaps itself – and slowing down faster than the galaxies are. But this would require the dark matter to be able to interact with itself in a completely new an unexpected way, a “dark force” that affects only dark matter.

Lawrence M. Krauss

> If you removed all of the particles, all of the radiation, absolutely everything from space and all that remained was nothing that nothing would weigh something."

What weighs something has mass.

If you remove everything else then all which remains is spacetime which means mass is associated with spacetime, correct?

Is it necessary for physicists to conjure a 'new dark force' or is it more likely mass is associated with spacetime and it is the mass associated with spacetime which 'piles up' analogous to the bow waves of two boats which pass by each other very closely?

Comment: The first quote is about dark matter.  The second is about dark energy.  I don't believe the two quotes really go together.  Are you asking "could dark matter be dark energy / vacuum energy piled up in one location?"

Comment: The second quote is also about what fills 'empty' space. Does 'empty' space have mass and if it does what does that mean in terms of the offset between the galaxy clusters and the light lensing through the space neighboring the galaxy clusters. Could it be analogous to a submarine moving through and displacing water? If there were lights beyond the submarine the light lensed from them would be offset from the center of the submarine just like the light lensed from beyond the galaxy clusters is offset from the center of the galaxy clusters, correct?

Comment: If there were some sort of massive / energetic ether being pushed around we'd see the astronomical drag effects and non-conservation of momentum.

Comment: "Relativity actually says nothing about the existence or nonexistence of matter pervading the universe [..] It turns out that such matter exists. ... Subsequent studies with large particle accelerators have now led us to understand that space is more like a piece of window glass than ideal Newtonian emptiness. It is filled with 'stuff' that is normally transparent but can be made visible by hitting it sufficiently hard to knock out a part." - Robert B. Laughlin, Nobel Laureate in Physics. Matter, a piece of window glass and 'stuff' have mass. The aether is, or behaves similar to, a supersolid.